# custom interface: what does buffer map to?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am working with sounddevice (python).
indata in RawStream is a buffer.
What should I map it to when creating a Custom Interface pls?

Thanks.
Regards,
G.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354010/custom-interface:-what-does-buffer-map-to?/) by [anthares](https://answers.ros.org/users/55473/anthares/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2020-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had just started with ROS/ROS2 when posting this.
I have found answer to my questions in here: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Concepts/About-ROS-Interfaces/

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [anthares](https://answers.ros.org/users/55473/anthares/) with karma: 60 on 2020-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0